# SQL column to display the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that I am using for my query in which one column has several typos.

This is a huge data base and the typos due to multiple people inputting the data and doing it their own way. I've decided to just have that column display one word.

For example, the column header is state in which the only state name in the column under location that  is `Mississippi`.

The problem is, I've come across words like `Miss`, `MS`, `IS`, `Ms`, `mS`, `Misisipi`, `Missippi`, etc.

I just want the location column to display `Mississippi` and it is hard for me to capture all of the current typos and any future typos that may be loaded into the database.

Is there a way for me to just have the location column in my query to have `Mississippi` on every row. Thanks!

Comment: If the only data that should be in the [STATE] column is "Mississippi" then why don't you just update every row to "Mississippi".

Comment: @danielsvic please share your code

Comment: You may want to take a look at SQL Server Data Quality Services.

Comment: The problem is, how can you be sure that all the data in that column means "Missisipi". Why don't you do a SELECT DISTINCT on that column to see all the different values you have? If you are sure that column must be equal to "Missisipi" then you can do an update as Cool_Br33ze suggest but if the value is constant, why do you need the column?

Answer (score 1):

You can just update that column for all rows if you want that to be the value:

```
UPDATE [TABLE]
SET State = 'Mississippi'
```

Otherwise, create a dummy column in your `SELECT` when you get the values if you really don't want to update that column:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 'Mississippi' as State
FROM [TABLE]
```